# Difference between window.location.href and this.router.url?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I know there could be many ways of getting current URL in Angular, such as:

```
this.router.url
```

However, my question is:
What benefits do I get by doing: **this.router.url** and not simply **window.location** ? Can someone explain that to me, please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Window.location.href depends on a browser. That makes unit testing difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you probably don't want to interface with the window or any global object directly. The reason for this is that angular can in theory run outside of a browser, so there would be no `window` or `document` and you would want to bridge this safely. `router` is doing exactly this

If you have a look at the docs you might get a better idea:

> In a tabbed browser, each tab is represented by its own Window object;
>   the global window seen by JavaScript code running within a given tab
>   always represents the tab in which the code is running. That said,
>   even in a tabbed browser, some properties and methods still apply to
>   the overall window that contains the tab, such as resizeTo() and
>   innerHeight. Generally, anything that can't reasonably pertain to a
>   tab pertains to the window instead.

This is true for a **tabbed browser**. A phone has another API to talk to things such as the camera. And the phone might also be missing some stuff which is present on the desktop.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that angular can in theory run outside of a browser?

Comment: well, javascript can run anywhere, e.g. on a phone with cordova or on a backend with node. The problem is that when running it anywhere else, the global vars will behave different or be missing.

Comment: However in any context you will have router available. It is mostly a design choice